# conditions on count in a select

Tags: sql-server, count

i have a table like this:

```
Table(MissioneID, Type)
```

Type can be 1,2 or 3

i have to count missions by type value:

ex. if table's  content is:

```
MissioneID Type
1,1
1,2
1,1
2,3
1,2
```

The result of query is

```
MissioneID,Count1,Count2,Count3
1, 2,2,0
2,0,0,1
```

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
    MissioneID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [type]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Count1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [type]=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Count2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [type]=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Count3
from
    [Table]
group by
    MissioneID
```

Comment: +1, correct answer. But you might want to encapsulate `type` in square brackets: `[type]` since it's a reserved word.

Comment: True, although it doesn't cause any problems in context, for 2000 or 2008. (Only error in above concerns having a table called Table)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to do a pivot query here:

```
SELECT MissioneID, [1], [2], [3]
FROM Table
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(Type)
    FOR Type IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: Nice answer - I keep forgetting any facilities available > 2000, since that's where I'm still unhappily languishing.

Comment: @Damien: Always good to remember your legacy workarounds, you never know when you'll need to use one.  I would have posted the `CASE` version as an alternate (since the question author didn't specify the SQL Server version) but you got to it first. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select type,count(*)
from table
group by MissioneID
```

Comment: I want a result with this columns:
MissioneID,CountType1,CountType2,CountType3

Not this Type,Count